# mvc4 webapi custom json serializer for specific type

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, c#-4.0, deserialization, json.net

I know MVC4 uses NewtonSoft Json de/serialization. I was wondering how I can exclude a property on serialization to client, without using any of the data annotations like JsonIgnore/DataMemberIngore etc (the assembly is used elsewhere and can't be changed. Can I implement a custom formatter/JsonSerializerSettings/Dynamic ContractResolver etc for a specific object type and then filter out a specific property name?

Any help much appreciated.

Edit. Came up with the following as a first attempt. If anyone has a more elegant solution please let me know...

```
public class DynamicContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    public DynamicContractResolver()
    {

    }

    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, Newtonsoft.Json.MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {

        IList<JsonProperty> properties = base.CreateProperties(type, Newtonsoft.Json.MemberSerialization.Fields);

        if (type == typeof(SomeType))
        {
            var matchedProp = properties.Where(v=> v.PropertyName=="SomeProperty").FirstOrDefault();
            if (matchedProp!=null)
            {
                properties.Remove(matchedProp);
            }
        }


        return properties;
    }
}
```

Plumbed into global.asax:

```
HttpConfiguration config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;
JsonSerializerSettings serializerSetting = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ContractResolver = new DynamicContractResolver(),
            ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize
        };

config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings = serializerSetting;
```

Regards
Phil

Answer (score 0):

### This is solvable with a proper overriding

1. Override a `Json` function(s) that is in the MVC `Controller` class.
   In this class you can customize the data. (with another mapping,
   with reflection, ...)
2. Create a custom JsonResult class, just override the default one. You
   are also able to override there the default serialization which is
   going on there.

   Now:

   - You can exclude this data when you already have a JSON
     serialized string ... This would be the easiest option. Basically just string operations.
   - On the other hand you will also be able to call a custom NewtonSoft
     serialization and you can do there whatever you want ... Even use custom serializations.

Comment: Thanks Peter, but I am using WebApi and didn't want to move back to Controller base wrapping with JsonResult